# How to connect to FTP via Winscp/Filezilla - Ubuntu server + VirtualBox - What should I add in "Port Forwarding"?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I have an Ubuntu Server on my Virtualbox.

In the virtual machine Network Settings I have it set to "NAT" and added in "Port Forwarding" the 80 port. So now when I run on my PC "localhost" or the hostname of the server or the IP of my local PC  (**IPv4 address - not the local IP of the Ubuntu server**) I get the localhost main apache page :) !

I tried connection to the FTP via WinSCP, and noticed that I just cant, so I figured that maybe I have to define some ports on "Port Forwarding" too.

I tried this:

[image]

I used my local IP address (not the local ubuntu ip) and the regular port 21 to connect to the FTP without any success.

any idea how to do that right? 
What part am I missing?

Comment: Do you have ftp server running and listening on port 21 in Ubuntu server?

Comment: I have "proftpd" installed. 
When I tried connecting using the Ubuntus local IP before swiching from "Bridged Adapter" to "NAT" I was able to connect. 
Should I so anything else from inside the server? Please explane :o !

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: `Timeout detected. (data connection)
Could not retrieve directory listing
Error listing directory '/home/myHostName'.`

Comment: Are you using active or passive mode? Check in Filezilla.

Comment: Use SSH, it has built-in file transfer properties and doesn't use the network in a [braindead way](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie#The_Client_Shall_Listen_For_Connections_From_The_Server.21) like FTP does.

Comment: @AndréBorie can you please explain more? any good tutorial ?

Comment: @Hatzil666 the SSH server you're already running supports SFTP, so you can just use a compatible client (Cyberduck, WinSCP, FileZilla, etc) to connect to it on port 22.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup passive ports for computers behind NAT according to  [Configuring ProFTPD behind NAT](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/NAT.html).

Here is how:

- First add the `PassivePorts` directive in your `proftpd.conf` to control what ports ProFTPD will use for its passive data transfers:

  ```
  PassivePorts 60000 65535    # just a suggestion, can be adjusted
  ```
- Restart ProFTPD.
- Now add this port range (60000-65535) in you NAT rule and try.

Comment: I'll try this in a sec :)

Comment: How do I add a range on Vboxs NAT ?

Comment: I added this: 
`MasqueradeAddress localhost` in the conf file too. 

and I get this new error: `Transfer channel can't be opened. Reason: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Could not retrieve directory listing` It kinda loggs in but kicks me out immediately

Comment: There seems no easy way to add port range to vbox nat rule. Your can see if ftp `active mode` works for you or you should go for bridge network interface.

Comment: Hmm I'll tell you what I'm trirying to do: I have a server on VBox. 
I want: 1) to be able to use the hostname to get to the main apache page and not only the IP/localhost. 2) Get all Computers on LAN to connect to it. (again, running the servers name and not the IP).

Comment: So I was told that I need to use Vboxes NAT for this and open port 80 - works. 
but now I cant connect to the FTP :(

Comment: You can do it easily if you have a local DNS server. You can add an entry there with the server ip address. This way everyone on lan can use it using name.

Comment: So I need to google "ubuntu server DNS" ?

Comment: Hmm, I installed Bind, and i'm in `named.conf.options`.